# Finding first gap in data from today looking back X days in sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to figure out a query to determine the first gap in data with a 1 week look back window, assuming that data is logged every per id.

So for example, if I have a table that has the following:

```
+------+----------------+
| id   | date           |
+----- +----------------+
|    1 | 5/4/2023       |
|    1 | 5/5/2023       |
|    1 | 5/6/2023       |
|    2 | 5/4/2023       |
|    2 | 5/5/2023       |
|    2 | 5/11/2023      |
+------+----------------+
```

Assuming today is `5/11/2023`, then in the above example I'd want to return the following:

```
+------+----------------+
| id   | first_gap      |
+----- +----------------+
|    1 | 5/11/2023      |
|    2 | 5/10/2023      |
+------+----------------+
```

For id = 1, we do not see the data logged today (5/11) so that's the first date in the 1 week lookback it's missing.

For id = 2, we see data logged for 5/11 but then don't see logging until 5/5. So the first missing date looking back 1 week is 5/10.

Edit: date is of type `datetimestamp`, I'm doing this on redshift

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products have their own set of functions.)

Comment: Column date data type?

Comment: Updated my original q. Date is datetimestamp and I'm doing this on redshift

Answer (score 1):

We could generate all possible combinations of ids and dates of the week (using `generate_series` and a `cross join`), then filter out those that do exists in the table, and finally retain the top miss per group with aggregation:

```
select i.id, max(d.dt) max_missing_dt
from generate_series(current_date - interval '1 week', current_date, interval '1 day') d(dt)
cross join (select distinct id from mytable) i
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t where t.dt = d.dt and t.id = i.id
)
group by i.id
```

In normal usage, you would have a separate table to store the ids, which we could use instead of `select distinct`.

---

In Redshift, `generate_series` is not supported. Since we just need a handful of items, we could work around with a fixed table of numbers:

```
select i.id, max(d.dt) max_missing_dt
from (
    select current_date - n * interval '1 day' dt
    from (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7)) n(n)
) d
cross join (select distinct id from mytable) i
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t where t.dt = d.dt and t.id = i.id
)
group by i.id
```

Comment: Ah this is the route I'm trying to go now. Sorry I just realized even though Redshift is based on postgres, redshift does not allow to join `generate_series` with other tables. I've updated the question to reflect that I am doing this on redshift actually.

Comment: @Kevin: please tag your question correctly… I updated my answer with a Redshift solution.